# Differential equation $(x^2y^2-1)dy+2xy^3dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(x^2y^2-1)dy+2xy^3dx=0$

problem states that  $y=t^n$  must be used.
Using software it seems that there is a real solution.

$$\frac{1}{3} \left(-\frac{\sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{9 c_1^4-4 c_1^2 x^6}-9 c_1^2+2 x^6}}{\sqrt[3]{2} c_1}-\frac{x^2}{c_1}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} x^4}{c_1 \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{9 c_1^4-4 c_1^2 x^6}-9 c_1^2+2 x^6}}\right)$$
The question is how can I get there ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the $t^{n}$ is for, but have you tried using an integrating factor? I have not checked if the integration gets difficult afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x^2y^2-1)dy+2xy^3dx=0$$
Let  $X=x^2$ which leads to : $(X y^2-1)dy+y^3dX=0$
$$y^3\frac{dX}{dy}+y^2 X = 1 $$
Considering the unknown function $X(y)$, this is a linear ODE. It is easy to solve it. The general solution is :
$$X(y)=\frac{c}{y} -\frac{1}{y^2}$$ 
$$y^2 X-cy+1=0$$
$$y=\frac{c\pm\sqrt{c^2-4X}}{2X}$$
$$y=\frac{c\pm\sqrt{c^2-4x^2}}{2x^2}$$

Comment: Seems a nice solution. But I have two questions. Why it requires $y=t^n$ ? Also why in mathematica I got that result ?

Comment: What is $t$ ? You didn't defined the symbol $t$ in the wording of your question. How do you expect an answer without defining the symbols that you use. May be it is not $t^n$, but $x^n$. In this case, it is a quick method to find a particular solution usefull to simplify further calculus (a short-cut, in fact). You try $y=x^n$ and find $n$ so that the function be convenient. If it works, you have a solution. If it doesn't works, try something else.

Comment: Problem didnt define what is t. However looking at it again it seems that this is a way to solve the resulting Linear ODE ?(after using $ X=x^2$ ) Setting $t=y^3$ ?

Comment: Hi Parhs ! May be you made a mistake in using your software to solve the ODE because the result that you report is false. WolframAlpha give a much simpler result which is exactly the same as my own result on Dec.16 . See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2+y%5E2-1%29y%27%2B2x+y%5E3%3D0