# Solve differential equations $(x^2y^2-1)dy + 2xy^3dx = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Help me solve this:
$$(x^2y^2-1)dy + 2xy^3dx = 0$$

We now what:
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=2x^2y$$  and $$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=2y^3$$
I try to make it exact but get this:
$\frac{x^2-y^2}{xy^2}$
Help me!
may be substituchion $z = \frac{x^2-y^2}{xy^2}$ or we can be it more simple

Comment: You mixed things.. What is exactly M and N ?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070544/differential-equation-x2y2-1dy2xy3dx-0?rq=1)?

Comment: @alexey-burdin There's another way to solve it.

Comment: @Isham $M = x^2y^2-1$ and $N=2xy^3$ stadnt way to wtite this

Comment: You have to take derivative of M with respect to x not y. And for N it must be taken wrt y. Do the calculation again

Comment: @Isham Oh yeahh! i get $-\frac{1}{y}$ is it true? $\frac{(Mx-Ny)}{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE

$$M(x,y)\,\mathrm dx+N(x,y)\,\mathrm dy=0$$

is exact if

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

Here we have

$$M(x,y)=2xy^3\implies\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=6xy^2\\N(x,y)=x^2y^2-1\implies\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=2xy^2$$

so the equation is not exact. Introduce an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ such that the ODE

$$\mu(x,y)M(x,y)\,\mathrm dx+\mu(x,y)N(x,y)\,\mathrm dy=0$$

is exact, i.e.

$$\frac{\partial(\mu M)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial(\mu N)}{\partial x}\implies\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}M+\mu\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}N+\mu\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\\
\implies\frac1\mu\left(\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}(2xy^3)-\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}(x^2y^2-1)\right)=-4xy^2$$

Notice that if $\mu(x,y)=\mu(y)$ (independent of $x$), then $\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}=0$ and

$$\frac1\mu\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}=-\frac{4xy^2}{2xy^3}=-\frac2y\implies\ln|\mu|=-2\ln|y|\implies\mu=\frac1{y^2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah i did it, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:
$$(x^2y^2-1)dy + 2xy^3dx = 0$$
$$x^2y^2dy + 2xy^3dx = dy$$
$$x^2y^2dy + y^3d(x^2) = dy$$
$$y^2(x^2dy + yd(x^2)) = dy$$
$$d(yx^2) = \frac {dy}{y^2} \implies yx^2+\frac 1 y =C$$